# Using org.apache in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, apache-commons

I am trying to use org.apache from Matlab by doing this:

```
javaaddpath('~/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar');
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.correlation.*

c = org.apache.commons.math3.stat.correlation.KendallsCorrelation();
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined variable "org" or class "org.apache.commons.math3.stat.correlation.KendallsCorrelation"
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Can the problem be that Matlab is using Java 6 and I have Java 7 installed on my machine? If so, how do I fix this?

Comment: Turns out Kendall's correlation is not present in math version 3.2, but in 3.3. I've downloaded and imported that version and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

KendallsCorrelation class is present in math version 3.3 only and I was trying to use version 3.2. The following code works:

```
javaaddpath('~/matlab/jars/commons-math3-3.3/commons-math3-3.3.jar');
import org.apache.commons.math3.stat.correlation.*
c = org.apache.commons.math3.stat.correlation.KendallsCorrelation();
c.correlation([4 2 0], [3 2 1])
```